# How to get add a legend

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

I am trying to graph some data with shapefiles, but I need a legend to distinguish which shapefile is in which color. I assigned a color to each shapefile, but the tricky part is to create a legend.

My code is below:

```
data = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(data.INTPTLON, data.INTPTLAT))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
DC_BLK.plot(ax=ax,edgecolor = "black" ,facecolor = "None")

DC_BG.plot(ax=ax, edgecolor = "lightblue",facecolor = "None")

DC_CT.plot(ax=ax,edgecolor = "purple",facecolor = "None")

data.plot(ax=ax , marker = '.')

ax.set_title('Washington DC - 7x pop')

plt.show()
```

data. plot - plots three points using longitude & latitude onto the map.
DC_BLK - shapefile containing DC blocks
DC_BG - shapefile containing DC block groups
DC_CT - shapefile containing DC Census tract

Comment: What are DC_BLK, DC_BG, and DC_CT?

Comment: Have you tried `ax.legend()`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I wanted to post what I did just in case someone runs into a similar problem.
Here is what i did:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
data = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(data.INTPTLON, data.INTPTLAT))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
DC_BLK_PLT = DC_BLK.plot(ax=ax,edgecolor = "grey", facecolor = "None")
DC_BG_PLT = DC_BG.plot(ax=ax, edgecolor = "lightblue",facecolor = "None")
DC_CT_PLT = DC_CT.plot(ax=ax,edgecolor = "black",facecolor = "None")
data.plot(ax=ax , marker = '.')
grey  = mpatches.Patch(color = 'grey', label = 'Block')
Lblue = mpatches.Patch(color = 'Lightblue', label = 'Block Group')
Black = mpatches.Patch(color= 'black', label = 'Census Tract')
ax.set_title('Washington DC - 7x pop')
plt.legend(handles = [grey,Lblue,Black])
plt.show()
```

Hope this helps